# filters with Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet which I essentially use as a record of jobs.  I have a status column that I use to track the status of the job; there are about 8 status values.  I regularly use a filter through the spreadsheet interface to create different views e.g. 
show all outstanding jobs (status=inprog | pending_parts) 
show all completed jobs (status=paid | no_fault | abandoned).

This is ok but as I am quite familiar with the google scripting API, I thought I would create some menu customisations to give me the views that I regularly use.  Essentially I want to automate the selection of certain "tick" on the filter possibilities - However I can't identify the correct API to manipulate the filters; is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set formulas with apps script to retrieve data back to apps script. You would have to do something like get the data from your sheet and iterate over that data then maybe display the result in a new sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'll have to think of another way.